# Multi-color String (android)

Tags: android, html, string

i have a string in which i would like a component to take a green color. I have tried various ways without achieving any result unfortunately. Maybe somebody of you guys can help me with this.

Here is what i tried : 
Option 1 :

```
String b = "<font color = '#82FA58'>" + Integer.toString(deal.megadeal) + " " + mStrings.getString(AppStrings.textdeal) + "</font>";
ty.redeemText.setText(a + " " + Html.fromHtml(b)  +  " " + c);
```

Option 2 :

```
setText(a + " " + Html.fromHtml("<font color = '#82FA58'> " + b + "</font>")  + " " + c);
```

Comment: what is ty.redeemText ?

Comment: can you please post full adapter code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save all your Html string into one and use BufferType.SPANNABLE.

```
String b= partOfString + "<font color = '#82FA58'>" + greenstring + "</font>" + otherPartOfString;
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(b), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second option worked for me.

Try to do step-by-step, only color simple string, then add other text or variables.

```
setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#522D03'>Hi</font>"));
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#522D03'>Hi</font>]]>");
```

Let me know if one of above works.

Comment: I tried this it works fine, but when i add "a" it doesnt work. This is the line of code : setText(a + (Html.fromHtml("<font color='#522D03'>" + b + "</font>")));

Comment: Try this: setText((Html.fromHtml(a + "<font color='#522D03'>" + b + "</font>")));

Comment: Fondesa's solution worked, thanks for your involvment aletede

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
String megaDeal = Integer.toString(deal.megadeal);
String textDeal = mStrings.getString(AppStrings.textdeal);
String leftText = a + " ";
String rightText = " " + c;
String middleText = megaDeal + " " + textDeal;
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder( leftText +  middleText + rightText );
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#82FA58")), leftText.length(), leftText.length() +  middleText.length(), SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ty.redeemText.setText(span);
```